# Find the total sum of class fees based on the class students enrolled over specific years using mysql or php

Tags: php, mysql

I am calculating for the total payments that are made by each class and by the student in a class he or she has ever been enrolled in, depending on the Academic Year.

Now the `Student Class Table` below has two students, the student with `Student ID=0001` has been enrolled in two classes in two different years `Class ID = 1, Year=2013` and `Class ID=2, Year=2014`.

However the student with `Student ID=0002` only enrolled in one class and he left the school. Another student was enrolled in class with
`Class ID = 1` in `Year=2014`

```
    Student Class Table
    |   Student ID  |   Class ID    |   Year    |
    |      0001     |      1        |   2013    |
    |      0002     |      1        |   2013    |
    |      0003     |      1        |   2014    |
    |      0001     |      2        |   2014    |
```

Below is the amount assigned to each student for each class in a particular period.

```
    Designated Fees
    |   Class ID    |   Amount  |   Year    |
    |    1          |    100    |   2013    |
    |    1          |    120    |   2014    |
    |    2          |    210    |   2014    |
```

Now, I want to find the total amount each 'Class' is suppose to pay in the current year (thus in 2014), with the summation of what each class was suppose to pay in the previous year ( in this case, the 2013 is the previous Year) and the Previous Year (in this case, the 2014 is the current Year).

Using the below query will give you the amount each Student is suppose to pay from the previous year and current year as far is he/she enrolled in there.

This query gives a good results without any problems

```
        SELECT 
              a.`Student ID`,
              a.`Class ID`,
              b.`Amount`,
              a.`Year

        FROM 
             `Student Class Table` a
        JOIN 
             `Designated Fees` b
        ON
                a.`Class ID`=b.`Class ID`
                    and                                         
                 a.Year=b.Year


    QUERY RESULTS

    |   Student ID  |   Class ID    |   Amount  |   Year    |
    |      0001     |      1        |     100   |   2013    |
    |      0002     |      1        |     100   |   2013    |
    |      0003     |      1        |     120   |   2014    |
    |      0001     |      2        |     210   |   2014    |
```

I want find the total class fees for all the  years based on the students enrolled, using the current year as the base year, in this case year 2014 is the current year.

For instance

```
    |   Class ID    |   Total Fees  |   Year    |   
    |       1       |       120     |   2014    |
    |       2       |       410     |   2014    |
```

The `Total Fees` for the class with `Class ID=1` is `120` because only a student was enrolled in that class within the Year 2013 and 2014 and thier allocated fees for the year 2014 is 120, Also the `Total Fees` for the 
class with `Class ID=2` is `410` because two students were enrolled in class with `Class ID = 1` in Year 2013 and they were expected to pay an amount of 200, and in the Year 2014 Class 2, only one student enrolled and was expected to pay an amount of 210.

Well, my thoughts on solving this has been complicated, however I added a `group by` to the query afforementioned, this is wrong that I know. I wanted an Idea as to how to resolve this using either mysql or php, I can't seem to find my way around it.

Answer (score 1):

This will be possible if you have batch numbers for the class from the time, the class was registered. This students in such a class will bear the batch No till they complete the school.

For instance, students in class with `Class ID= 1` in `Year=2013` will bear the same batch No till they complete. You can choose to create another table and reference it in the `Student Class Table` depending on how you promote students through the classes over the years.

```
Student Class Table
|   Student ID  |   Class ID    |   Year    |  BatchNo    |
|      0001     |      1        |   2013    |     1       |
|      0002     |      1        |   2013    |     1       |
|      0003     |      1        |   2014    |     2       |
|      0001     |      2        |   2014    |     1       |
```

After Adding the Batch No, you can simply `group by` the batchNo and sum the amount:

```
  SELECT 
          a.`Student ID`,
          a.`Class ID`,
          sum(b.`Amount`),
          a.`Year

    FROM 
         `Student Class Table` a
    JOIN 
         `Designated Fees` b
    ON
            a.`Class ID`=b.`Class ID`
                and                                         
             a.Year=b.Year
  GROUP BY batchNo
```

This will be your Results

```
|   Class ID    |   Total Fees  |   Year    |   
|       1       |       120     |   2014    |
|       2       |       410     |   2014    |
```

You can go by this idea and I think, it can work well.

Comment: This looks promising, please will try and get back to you, Thanks @George